# Kdenlive gone from system, and won't re install?

Tags: kde, dependencies, video-editor, kdenlive

I have posted this on the Kdenlive forum but been advised to try elsewhere as this seems to be an OS related issue, so here goes...

I have been using Kdenlive happily for a while on Ubuntu 14.04LTS(just 'vanilla' Ubuntu with Unity desktop). But today Kdenlive seems to have disappeared from my system!

Software Update did update a number of the KDE apps I have installed (mainly Kontact), I wonder if this is related?
On trying to re install Kdenlive I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
kdenlive : Depends: libnepomuk4 (>= 4:4.5.85) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm relatively new to Linux so would be grateful if any replies would be good enough to take that into consideration; I'm quite happy to be patronised if I learn something along the way :)

Can anybody help? I was really enjoying Kdenlive and have some projects in it I really don't want to abandon.

With thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to install the libnepomuk4 ? Do you get an error message ? What kind of error ?

Comment: Are you using the Ubuntu repository version or the upstream (Kdenlive) recommend version ? The Kdenlive recommends: https://kdenlive.org/download-ubuntu .

Comment: I have tried installing libepomuk4 from Software Centre and get the following error: The following packages have unmet dependencies:

"_libnepomuk4: Depends: libkdecore5 (= 4:4.13.3-0ubuntu0.2) but 4:4.14.2-0ubuntu1~ubuntu14.04~ppa1 is to be installed
Depends: libkdeui5 (= 4:4.13.3-0ubuntu0.2) but 4:4.14.2-0ubuntu1~ubuntu14.04~ppa1 is to be installed_"

Comment: I have tried the Ubuntu repository and the 'sunab' upstream ppa. I get the same outcome.

Comment: It seems that you are using the Kubuntu backports PPA ? A link:https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=269&t=122406 .